# Stack two <td> over each other

Tags: html, css, html-table

I'm currently working on making a website responsive but the issue is, I need to make it responsive without touching the content of the page. 
So everything stays the same on the page, but with a new stylesheet and a little Javascript (but mainly CSS) I'm looking to accomplish this task.

The website is made mostly with tables.. so when the browser is resized (or accessed with a mobile device), I want the second 'td' inside my 'tr' to stack under the first one instead of both being next to each other.

I gave the 'td' element a left float and a width of 100% and it worked fine in Firefox, but in Chrome & Safari, both 'td' are 50% and on the same line.

Let me know if you have any ideas, anything is appreciated!

Comment: Don't use tables for layout.

Comment: I'm afraid that's not how TDs work. TDs stay on one line and can only be placed onto another line by being placed into another TR.

Comment: -Oded, like I said, the content is not in my control. The content of the page is generated and I have no access to that code.
-Billy, I understand that, but that's why I'm asking here, so maybe someone has a solution of some sort.

Comment: I think you're really up against it with the task you have here if you're not able to alter your html.

Answer (score 37):

Use `display:block` on your `tr td` to adapt the layout.

```css
tr td {
  padding: 20px 40px;
  border: 1px solid black;
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>Damn</td>
    <td>This</td>
    <td>Table</td>
    <td>Layout</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 4):

Try with CSS changing the display, so it goes to the other line:

```
td {
  display: block;
  clear:both;
}
```

See an example [just made](http://jsfiddle.net/LBTCk/)

Comment: Thanks! Someone also did something similar. I'll try this out right now.

Comment: the clear was suggested if you needed to use float (right or left) to make sure it goes to the other line.

Answer (score 1):

What your trying to do will either not work or cause you a massive headache. Tables aren't designed to be used for responsive design. If you say you can't touch the code then you're very stuck. The best way to get around this would be to re-write the code and replace any tables with DIVs, Ps etc. where relevant and the use CSS, jquery and media queries to make your site responsive.

The only way you can try make the site responsive currently would be to use jquery on page load to replace all the tables with DIVs, Ps etc and then go about using CSS, jquery and media queries to try and make the site responsive. This is not a recommended way to do it and I can't even guarantee this will work 100%.

Comment: Finally someone who read everything I said. I have no control over the generated content, it's a government website, so it's outdated, but they don't do anything about it, so I have to work with what I have... which is table layouts. Thanks for the reply though! I wanted to avoid jQuery as much as possible because I know it's not the best way to do it.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried putting two `div`s inside the table cell with a `float left` on them.  When the table collapses they should stack.

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply. It's a government website, so I cannot touch any of the content on the page. Like I replied above, the content is generated and I don't have access to that. I'm only trying to create a mobile solution for the website. As much as I'd want the site to be made with divs, it's not possible for now. In the future maybe if they realize the website is outdated I will be able to make a proper job, but for now it's not in my power.

Answer (score 0):

Another possibility is to nest the government site inside an `iframe`, that way you can use something like JQuery to do whatever you want to the site.

Comment: That entirely depends on what access the containing document would have over the iframe content.

Comment: The idea is that it's working client side on the markup that's already generated - the server can't really restrict what has already been passed over...

Answer (score -2):

Sounds like you're using tables for layout and *not* tabular data. Tables should *only* be used for tabular data.

You'd need to use [grouping content](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/grouping-content.html) instead; more specifically, the [`div` element](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/grouping-content.html#the-div-element):

```
<div>
    <div>Top</div>
    <div>Bottom</div>
</div>
```

It's worth noting that depending on what type of content is present within your top and bottom containers you may want to use a [different element altogether](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/text-level-semantics.html).

Comment: Like I replied on other answers, I know this is the best way, and that's how I usually do it. But I don't have control over the content on the page of the website, I've just been asked to try and make a mobile solution for the site. So as much as I hate it, I can't do anything about it. Thanks!

Comment: Unfortunately he can't modify the original content in that way.

Comment: The problem is that a table is a table. A table has rows and columns. What you're trying to do is turn a table into something which *isn't* a table. You'll have to speak with whoever does have control over the content and get it changed.

Comment: @JamesDonnelly That's not always an option, unfortunately.

Comment: @Westie when it isn't an option you simply turn down the work. Doing this goes completely against the HTML specification and is really bad practice.

Comment: Thanks James, I wish it was that easy though! (well it is that easy, but re-doing the whole site is not!)

Comment: If you've been contracted to redesign a website then you need to make clear what needs changing on their site in order for this to be possible. In doing this work you're potentially giving your company a bad reputation.